# Pass translated text as a prop

Tags: reactjs, redux, localization, internationalization, react-intl

For localization, I am using React-intl. I am exporting below(intl.js) -

```
import { injectIntl } from 'react-intl';

const Intl = injectIntl(({ intl, children }: any) => children(intl));

const t = (
id: string | Array<string>,
values: Object | void,
) => <Intl>{i => i.formatMessage({ id }, values)}</Intl>;

export default t;
```

And in the place where I need to translate strings, I am importing above file like -

```
import t from '../../../components/intl.js';
```

I have the en.json file which have the translations defined, like -

```
"tri-pod":"tripod"
```

I am able to use translation like -

```
<span>{t`tri-pod`}</span>
```

Where I am facing problem is how to use the translations while sending as props like given below-

```
<mylabel label="tripod"></mylabel>
```

Adding label={t`tri-pod`} errors out.
What is the correct way to send the translated string itself as props?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `t` helper is that it doesn't output translated string as it's expected from i18n helper but outputs `<Intl>` element. This limits its possible uses.

In order to get translated string with `t`, a component likely should be enhanced with higher-order component:

```
const withT = Comp => injectIntl(({ intl, ...props}) => <Comp
  t={(id, values) => intl.formatMessage({ id }, values)}
  {...props}
/>);
```

Then `t` helper will be available as `t` prop in enhanced components.